# Cauchy product of $1+2+4+8+16+32+\dots$ and $1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Cauchy product of  $1+2+4+8+16+32+\dots$ and $1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$.

Then 
$c_1=1\times 1=1$
$c_2=1\times(-1)+2\times 1=-1+2$
$c_3=1-2+4$
$c_4=-1+2-4+8$
$\dots$
so when $n$ is even $s_n=\sum^{n/2}_1 2^{2n-1}$, when $s$ is odd, $s_n=\sum^{(n+1)/2}_12^{2(n-1)}$.

But the solution says it's $(2^{n+1} +(-1)^n)/3$.
Where am I wrong or just the solution is wrong?

Comment: YOu aren't done.  What is $\sum 2^{2n-1}$ equal to? (Use geometric sum formula $\sum_{k=0}^m ar^k = a\frac {r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}$.  Use $2^{2n-1} = 2\cdot 2^{2n-2} = 2\cdot 4^{n-1}$ )

Comment: Could you check the formula you typed for the solution you mention? For $n=4$, it isn't even an integer.

Comment: @Bernard Should be $(2^{n+1} +(-1)^n)/3$

Comment: Do you start the index for series at $k=1$? What you call $c_1$ is actually $c_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have shifted the indices in series, which start at $0$ (I recall $0\in\mathbf N$). Therefore, you have
\begin{align}
c_0&=1,&c_1&=-1+2, & c_2&=1-2+4, &c_3&=-1+2-4+8, 
\end{align}
and more generally
$$ c_n=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n (-2)^k=(-1)^n\,\frac{1-(-2)^{n+1}}{1-(-2)^{\phantom{n+1}}} . $$
Can you proceed?

Comment: It's generally accepted that $$0 \not\in \Bbb N =\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$$ and instead we use $$\Bbb N_0=\Bbb N\cup\{0\}=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but Peano's axioms include $0$. Without $0$, you don't have an additive monoid.

Comment: @RhysHughes It's not "generally accepted", because both of them are in use by different people.